# SQL Server Profiler - View Dynamic Sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am building and executing some dynamic sql and wanted to use SQL Server profiler to view that execution statement.  Do you know what filters /settings I have to use in order to see that? I have looked through them and could be just looking right over the obvious setting.

EDIT:

The dynamic sql is called within a procedure.

Thanks in Advance,

--S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following your edit you would need either the `SP:StmtCompleted` or `SP:StmtStarting` events (You can find these in the "Stored Procedures" section).

This might collect quite a lot of data so apply appropriate filters.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `SQL:BatchCompleted` event in the `TSQL` category and make sure you have the `TextData` column checked/shown.  The `Standard (default)` template includes these already.

Comment: Thanks Daniel the dynamic sql is called within a procedure. Does that change the config?

Comment: I'm not sure; it might work if you're `sp_executesql` or `EXEC` ing some SQL but if it doesn't try turning on the `SQL:StmtCompleted` event too.